# TokenNotFound Message: User not found in token cache. Maybe the server was restarted

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have the following function to call users from active directory use graph api. This function is hit on each keyup of a text box. But i am getting following error

Code: TokenNotFound Message: User not found in token cache. Maybe the server was restarted.

in this line of code

```
var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

My class

```
 public class GraphSdkHelper : IGraphSdkHelper
    {
        private readonly IGraphAuthProvider _authProvider;
        private GraphServiceClient _graphClient;

        public GraphSdkHelper(IGraphAuthProvider authProvider)
        {
            _authProvider = authProvider;
        }

        // Get an authenticated Microsoft Graph Service client.
        public GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(ClaimsIdentity userIdentity)
        {
            _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async requestMessage =>
                {
                    // Get user's id for token cache.
                    var identifier = userIdentity.FindFirst(Startup.ObjectIdentifierType)?.Value + "." + userIdentity.FindFirst(Startup.TenantIdType)?.Value;

                    // Passing tenant ID to the sample auth provider to use as a cache key
                    var accessToken = await _authProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync(identifier);

                    // Append the access token to the request
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                    // This header identifies the sample in the Microsoft Graph service. If extracting this code for your project please remove.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Add("SampleID", "aspnetcore-connect-sample");
                }));

            return _graphClient;
        }
    }
    public interface IGraphSdkHelper
    {
        GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(ClaimsIdentity userIdentity);
    }
}
```

Starup class

```
   public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public const string ObjectIdentifierType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier";
        public const string TenantIdType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid";

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options)).AddCookie();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            // Add application services.
            //services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
            services.AddSingleton<IGraphAuthProvider, GraphAuthProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IGraphSdkHelper, GraphSdkHelper>();

            //Connection string 
            services.AddDbContext<PFEContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PFEContext")));

            //Group authorization 
            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Customer", policyBuider =>
                policyBuider.RequireClaim("groups", "fb721f47-a58c-450a-9fbd-ff13f5960049")));
            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Developper", policyBuider =>
                policyBuider.RequireClaim("groups", "4fad5c4d-9bf9-477b-8814-02dffea5f102")));
            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("ProjectManager", policyBuider =>
                policyBuider.RequireClaim("groups", "635b3fff-bb39-4726-8d76-1fef66fb2e8c")));
            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("Tester", policyBuider =>
                policyBuider.RequireClaim("groups", "484d8c6c-f458-422f-9e0a-66a971874f3c")));



        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

i need same help to fix this problem , what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is probably caused by the token that is not well persisting in memory cache,

Otherwise, maybe you are restarting your apps when you close the browser so you need to disable this option in VS because when you restarting the app it's clear all temporary data in memrory .

you can follow these steps disabling this feature:

Go into **Tools** -> **Options**, then navigate into **Projects and Solutions** -> **Web Projects** and **uncheck** the option **Stop debugger when the browser window is closed**.